# facebook like action in ios

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface

I have integrated facebook SDK in ios,and now want to use `like` action. For this, I have used like logo of facebook but this is rejected with following message-

> "Please address the following feedback from our review team. Once you have made the changes listed below you may resubmit for review.
>   Thanks for making changes to your submission. This action type still doesn’t meet our criteria to become available to users. Here are the remaining changes that you need to make to your action type: Your button branding doesn’t follow Section 5.6 of the Facebook Terms and Section I.8 of the Platform Policy: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/branding/ The graphics must reflect your own branding and the user experience of your site. Learn more about branding: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process/#uex."

If I will use `like` button as my application theme, then how user will know that he is going to like on facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to facebook

> You can use the Built-in Like action to create custom buttons in your
>   app, but the button must not emulate or otherwise copy the design of
>   Facebook’s Like buttons. For example, you may not use a “thumbs up”
>   image with the word “like” in your Open Graph actions without prior
>   written permission from Facebook, and any custom like button you
>   create must not confuse users into thinking that your Open Graph
>   action will result in a connection to a Facebook Page.

They have clearly stated that "**you may not use a “thumbs up” image with the word “like”**"

So what's best thing which you can do ??

just a thumbs Up button.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be allowed to use same button as Facebook has, as per Apple's guidlines.

So, in that case, you can put the same button but with different color OR you can even change the sign of fingers and make a little change in the icon. It will create an impression of Facebook like button but it is not exactly same as it.